# How do I use a method of a class who's object I'm using in another class?

Tags: list, class, python-3.x, methods

Basically something like this

```
class Key:

    def __init__(self, pressed):
        '''(Key, bool) -> NoneType
        '''
        self._pressed = pressed

    def change_press_state(self):
        self._pressed = not self._pressed

class KeyBoard:

    def __init__(self, how_many):
        '''(KeyBoard, int) -> NoneType
        Makes a Keyboard of 'how_many' keys.
        '''

        self._keys = []
        for i in range (0, how_many):
            self._keys.append(KeyBoard(False))

    def switch_status_of_key(self, index_of_key):
        '''(KeyBoard) -> NoneType
        Presses key if isn't and stops pressing key if it is.
        '''
```

How would I call change_press_state on the specific key the user wants to switch in switch_status_of_key?
I was thinking something like

```
self._keys[key] = self._keys[key].flip()
```

But obviously not because I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
self._keys.append(KeyBoard(False))
```

should be:

```
  self._keys.append(Key(False))
```

and

```
def switch_status_of_key(self, index_of_key):
        '''(KeyBoard) -> NoneType
        Presses key if isn't and stops pressing key if it is.
        '''
        self._keys[index_of_key].change_press_state()
```

Comment: Ah right! No equals and thanks for the catches I just made an arbitrary quickly with those mistakes.